# Cosmos DB query NOT LIKE, CONTAINS NOT

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

How can I query Contains NOT in Cosmos DB.
For example, I want to find users whose email **does not** contain **xerox.com**

SELECT * FROM c WHERE CONTAINS(c.email, "xerox.com", false)

This gives me users whose email contains xerox.com but I want reverse of this, means user whose email **does not contain** string xerox.com

Comment: Intuitively, I think it would be `SELECT * FROM c WHERE NOT CONTAINS(c.email, "xerox.com", false)`. [The CosmosDB documentation shows it has a `NOT` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-operators#:~:text=NOT%20operator).

Comment: Note that CONTAINS can get expensive depending on item count and size. It may be worth storing something like EmailDomain separately to use an = check on instead, if performance relevant. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-contains#remarks

Answer (score 4):

Adding NOT before CONTAINS works.

eg.
SELECT * FROM c WHERE NOT CONTAINS(c.email, "xerox.com", false)